# calculate total votes in jQuery upvote plugin

Tags: php, mysql

I am really confused to solve this problem. Currently I have a jQuery upvote Plugin in my project. So, with every I click upvote it saves the value in the db as a true, with every vote taken back it save the value as false in the database and saves the value in the other column as 0. All I was trying to do is to count the total number of votes just like stack overflow does. Even now I am so confuse to on how to solve this issue. I end up making this code in php which is also make my whole program slow:

```
$sample1 = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * from Ratings WHERE TopicID = :current");
$sample1->bindParam(':current', $id);
$sample1->execute();
$RES1 = $sample1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
$upVote = 0;

foreach ($RES1 as $mk){
     if(($mk['Upvote'] === 'true') && ($mk['Downvote'] ==='false')){
             $upVote++;
                                    }
     else if(( $mk['Upvote'] ==='false') && ($mk['Downvote'] === 'true')){
             $upVote--;
                                }
     else if(($mk['Upvote'] === 'false') && ($mk['Downvote'] === 'false')){
            $upVote--;
                                }
     else if(($mk['Downvote'] === 'false')){
             $upVote++;
                                }
     else if(($mk['Downvote'] === 'true') && ($mk['Upvote'] ==='0') || ($mk['Upvote'] === 'false')){
             $upVote--;
     }

 }
```

My table structure :
[image: table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do it in the database-side and rewrite your query like that:

```
SELECT ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Ratings WHERE TopicID = :current AND Upvote = true) - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Ratings WHERE TopicID = :current AND Downvote = true)) AS total_votes
```

and on PHP-side just fetch `total_votes`:

```
$sample1 = $this->db->prepare("SELECT ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Ratings WHERE TopicID = :current AND Upvote = true) - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Ratings WHERE TopicID = :current AND Downvote = true)) AS total_votes");
$sample1->bindParam(':current', $id);
$sample1->execute();
$result = $sample1->fetch(); 
$total_votes = $result->total_votes;
```